# Manejo de arrays en Java: imprimir en pantalla el nombre de la persona de mayor edad y el de menor edad

Tags: java, array

Debo desarrollar un programita sencillo que de solución a lo siguiente:

1. Capturar nombres de personas con su respectiva edad.
2. Como resultado me piden que de los `arrays` capturados imprima en pantalla el nombre de la persona de mayor edad y el de menor edad.

Anexo fragmento de mi programa.

Esto es lo que llevo codificado al momento:

```
package arreglo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author horicho
 */
public class Arreglo3 {

    public static int mayor;
    public static int menor;
    public static int tamaño = 4;
    public static String[] nombres = new String[tamaño];
    public static int[] edad = new int[tamaño];
    public static int[] respaldo = new int[tamaño];
    public static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) {
            System.out.println("Captura el nombre de la persona: " + (i + 1) + "");
            nombres[i] = scn.next();
            System.out.println("Ingresa la edad: " + (nombres[i]) + "");
            edad[i] = scn.nextInt();
            respaldo[i] = edad[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) {
            Arrays.sort(edad);
            System.out.println("" + edad[j]);
            if (edad[j] > mayor) {
                mayor = nombres[j];

            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("La mayor edad es: " + mayor);
    }

}
```

Mi problema consiste en que cuando ordeno de mayor a menor y saco el dato mayor de ese array, no sé cómo realizar el enlace de los índices del array de respaldo con el índice del array con nombres para imprimir este dato en vez de la edad, que es lo que tengo hasta ahorita.

Comment: El problema principalmente es que estás usando Arrays.sort(edad);, pero aquí se pierde la relación del array edad con los demás array, no es necesario en este caso ordenar.

Answer (score 1):

En el bucle al encontrar la mayor edad debes de actualizar a la variable mayor para que se vaya comparando la edad de los demás usuarios sucesivamente.

No necesitas ordenar la edad, ya que en este caso tienes varios arreglos que solo son relacionados por el indice.

```
public static int mayor = 0;
public static int menor;
public static int tamaño = 4;
public static String[] nombres = new String[tamaño];
public static int[] edad = new int[tamaño];
public static int[] respaldo = new int[tamaño];
public static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
public static String personaMayorEdad;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) {
            System.out.println("Captura el nombre de la persona: " + (i + 1) + "");
            nombres[i] = scn.next();
            System.out.println("Ingresa la edad: " + (nombres[i]) + "");
            edad[i] = scn.nextInt();
            respaldo[i] = edad[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) {
            //Arrays.sort(edad);
            //System.out.println("Edad:" + edad[j]);
            if (edad[j] > mayor) {
                //mayor = nombres[j]; 
                mayor = edad[j]; //Define mayor edad, para seguir comparandola en el bucle.
                personaMayorEdad = nombres[j];
            }
        }
        
    menor = mayor; //define la variable menor con el valor mayor para realizar la comparaciòn.
    for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) {
        if (edad[j] < menor) {                
            menor = edad[j]; //Define menor edad, para seguir comparandola en el bucle.
            personaMenorEdad = nombres[j];
        }
    }
    
    
    System.out.println("La persona con mayor edad es: " + personaMayorEdad);
    System.out.println("La persona con menor edad es: " + personaMenorEdad);
    }
```

---

Ejemplo:

```
Captura el nombre de la persona: 1
Horacio
Ingresa la edad: Horacio
25
Captura el nombre de la persona: 2
Jorge
Ingresa la edad: Jorge
19
Captura el nombre de la persona: 3
Ioana
Ingresa la edad: Ioana
3
Captura el nombre de la persona: 4
Marta
Ingresa la edad: Marta
21
```

Salida:

```
La persona con mayor edad es: Horacio
La persona con menor edad es: Ioana
```

Answer (score 0):

para poder vincular el indice del mayor con el arreglo del nombre, es necesario hacer la ordenación de forma diferente a usar el método Sort, ya que este te mueve los indices.

Para esto es necesario declarar el valor inicial de la Edad y el nombre con el primer elemento del arreglo (indice 0) antes del ciclo y luego ir comparando como lo estás haciendo. Al encontrar algún dato Mayor, el mismo indice de la edad es el indice del Nombre.

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arreglo3 {

    public static int mayor;
    public static int menor;
    public static int tamaño = 4;
    public static String[] nombres = new String[tamaño];
    public static int[] edad = new int[tamaño];
    public static int[] respaldo = new int[tamaño];
    public static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String nombreMayor;
    public static String nombreMenor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) {
            System.out.println("Captura el nombre de la persona: " + (i + 1) + "");
            nombres[i] = scn.next();
            System.out.println("Ingresa la edad: " + (nombres[i]) + "");
            edad[i] = scn.nextInt();
            respaldo[i] = edad[i];
        }

        mayor = edad[0];
        nombre = nombres[0];

        for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) {
            if (edad[j] > mayor) {
                mayor = edad[j];
                nombreMayor = nombres[j];
            }
        }

        menor = mayor;

        for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) {
            if (edad[j] < menor) {
                menor = edad[j];
                nombreMenor = nombres[j];
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("La mayor edad es: " + mayor + " y la persona es: " + nombreMayor);
        System.out.println("La menor edad es: " + menor + " y la persona es: " + nombreMenor);
    }

}
```